# Suppose $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }x_{n}=x\neq 0$. Then $\left(\dfrac {1} {x_{n}}\right) _{n}$ is bounded.

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation

Suppose all $x_n\not=0$ and $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }x_{n}=x\neq 0$. Then $\left( \dfrac {1} {x_{n}}\right) _{n}$ is bounded.

*Proof.* There is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $\left| x_{n}-x\right| < \dfrac {1} {2}\left| x\right|$.

Now, for $n\geq N$, $\left| x\right|=\left| x-x_n+x_n\right|\leq\left| x-x_n\right|+\left| x\right|<\dfrac {1} {2}\left| x\right|+\left| x_n\right|$

Hence, we obtain,

$\dfrac {1} {2}\left| x\right|<\left| x_n\right|$.

Thus, for $n\geq N$, we have $\dfrac {1} {\left| x_n\right|}<\dfrac {2} {\left| x\right|}$. Therefore,

$B=1+\max\left\{ \dfrac {1} {\left| x_0\right|},\dfrac {1} {\left| x_1\right|},\ldots,\dfrac {1} {\left| x_n\right|},\ldots,\dfrac {1} {\left| x_N\right|},\dfrac {2} {\left| x\right|}\right\}$

is an upper bound for $\left( \dfrac {1} {x_n}\right)_n$.

**My question is**: In the $B$, why did we add $1$ to $\max$? Why did we need it, can you explain?

Comment: It's absolutely superfluous.

Comment: @Cauchy Why? Can you explain?

Comment: @Cauchy I fully agree, there is NO need to add anything at all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only have to add a quantity greater than $1$, to ensure that we have a strict inequality. The choice of $1$ is just a natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this if a usual bound ($\frac{1}{|x_n|}\leq B$) is required, but if $\frac{1}{|x_n|}< B$ is required (then called a *strict bound*) you must add some $b>0$ (as José said, but not necessarily greater than $1$).